# Goals counting for 2 goal types where conversion page matches

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have two goals on my website: premium subscriptions and basic subscriptions.

The conversion page is the same: regex: `secure/submitorder|secure/common/callback`

But the path for each is slightly different:
For basic:

1. example.com/start_basic
2. example.com/enter_payment_details
3. example.com/thank_you

For premium:

1. example.com/start_premium
2. example.com/enter_payment_details
3. example.com/thank_you

I've added the funnel for each step in the Universal Analytics goal admin.

Goal starts are different for each of premium and basic but goals for the day exactly match for both premium and basic.

How can I tell GA that those who arrive at the destination from /start_premium are premium goals and basic otherwise?

Comment: You need different destination urls for both goals (if you can't change the physical url you might want to use a virtual pageview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you have two goals? One for basic and one for premium.

Basic:

1. example.com/start_basic
2. example.com/enter_payment_details
3. example.com/thank_you

Destination URL: secure/submitorder (or whichever is the basic destination url)

Premium:

1. example.com/start_premium
2. example.com/enter_payment_details
3. example.com/thank_you

Destination URL: secure/common/callback (or whichever is the premium destination url)

Unless I'm missing something. BTW, this would probably be better suited under [StackOverflow Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: yes - apologies for not being clearer. The problem is that I have set up two goals: Premium Subs and Basic subs. They share the same conversion page but have a unique funnel path. The question is why do both premium and basic goal completes exactly match? It's like GA is crediting both goals when a visitor sees the conversion page.
RE webmasters yes you are right. I wanted to test if I'd get a bigger response over here, webmasters is a little less busy. I've noticed people "migrating" my questions in the past but I don;t think I have that ability

Comment: That is because that what happens - the goal is determined by the destination page for the goal, if they share the destination page both goals will be credited. The funnel is helpful for your reports but is not part of what determines the goal.